# How to bind Custom attached property to CheckBox.IsChekedProperty in code behind?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have the attached property and i want to bind this to CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty.

```
  public static object GetIsCheckedState(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(IsCheckedStateProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsCheckedState(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsCheckedStateProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsCheckedState.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsCheckedState", typeof(object), typeof(GridCellCheckBoxRenderer), new PropertyMetadata(null,OnIsCheckedStateChanged));

    private static void OnIsCheckedStateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = d as CheckBox;
        checkBox.IsChecked = (bool?)e.NewValue;
    }
 uiElement.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("IsCheckedState"), Source = uiElement});
```

Is the correct way to bind the attached property like above in UWP?

Comment: is uiElement is checkbox control?

Comment: If so, uiElement.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("IsCheckedState"), Source = uiElement}) is wrong. You gave source=uielement which is checkbox which doesnt have IsCheckedState property,unless you have declared your DependencyProperty in subclass of checkbox. Please explain your use case. Post codes which are required

Comment: Yes. In the above code uiElement is CheckBox Control. How can i bind my attached property to CheckBox.IsChecked property in two way mode?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Why do you want to bindit to checkbox IsChecked ?

Comment: you want to do <Checkbox attProp:AttachedPropertiesClassName.AttachedProperty="<your binding>" /> in code behind? that is different than what you are asking now.

Comment: Hi, My use case is bind the null values to CheckBox in UWP. But Null values binding is not supported directly in Windows store apps. so we can achieve this by Customizing the CheckBox or by using Behavior. so instead of using this approach i want to do this with one attached property and have tried to bind this attached property (IsCheckedStateProperty) to CheckBox.IsChecked property. Can you get this?

Comment: Have you checked this http://xaml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Blog/201406-NullableCheckbox/AttachedProperties/NullableCheckboxProperty.cs ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what your usecase is?
You can set an attachedProperty in the xaml and Bind it to some source:

```
<Checkbox attProp:AttachedPropertiesClassName.AttachedProperty="<your binding>" />
```